# Best way to redirect url with extra trailing slashes in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-urls

What is the best way to redirect a url like "mywebsite.com///" to "mywebsite.com/" in django?

Is there a setting that I can use in the settings.py file that is kind of the opposite of `APPEND-SLASH` or do I have to use

`from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to`

and add a urlpattern in the urls.py file?

Edit: 
I not trying to just make the webpage the same as "mywebsite.com/" i'm trying to get the actual url to change to "mywebsite.com/". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is there's a rewrite engine or a `.htaccess` hidden file in your file manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this at the application level I'd avoid creating new urlconf rules, specially if it's a global thing.

You can make your own middleware to handle this redirect automatically, as django does in the common middleware for appending slashes using the APPEND_SLASH setting here is the code for reference: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/common.py#L66-80

Also you may find the solution on this blog post useful: http://gregbrown.co.nz/code/append-or-remove-slash/

Answer (score 1):

You should add a url pattern in the urls.py file that will match this url, with the added slashes, if you wish.

Each pattern is just a regular expression, so you can tell it to match any url with extra slashes pretty easily.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
('^your/url/*$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/your/url/'}),
)
```

By adding /* to the url pattern it will match /your/url/ with any number of slashes after it.